# MSAccess - Look up Value in table - DoCmd.SearchForRecord

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to put a user input data validation check in.. simply take the value entered an input box (in this case it’s the job card number and make sure it exists in a table..

I’ve tried DoCmd.SearchForRecord, CurrentDb.OpenRecordset and Dcount but can’t get any of them working

I'm trying to get  **true** or ***false***... does **JobInput** appear in **[tblRouting]![Job Number]** …its driving me nuts.. can anyone help with whats the right way &  how its done??

The table I’m looking in is called tblRouting
The field is Job Number [tblRouting]![Job Number]
The value I’m looking up is JobInput

This is what I’ve got… *(it doesn't work)*

```
  Dim JobInput As String
    Dim rs As String
 If Me.AttachServJobNumber = 0 Then
    JobInput = InputBox("Please Enter a vaild job Number", "ATTACHMENT LINK TO JOB NUMBER", "Enter Job Number here")
    If JobInput = "Enter Job Number here" Or JobInput = "" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Else
    DoCmd.SearchForRecord acTable, "tblRouting", acFirst, "[tblRouting]![Job Number]=JobInput"
MsgBox ("Serial number already in use")
 End If
```

'''
I'v also tried these approaches... returns an object required error

```
If CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select count(*) tblRouting where JobInput=" & [tblRouting]![Job Number]!JobInput & ";").Fields(0) > 0 Then
MsgBox ("Serial number already in use")
```

'''

```
If DCount("JobInput", "tblRouting", "JobInput=" & [tblRouting]![Job Number]!JobInput) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Serial number already in use")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use *DLookup* for such simple cases:

```vb
Dim JobInput    As String

If Me.AttachServJobNumber = 0 Then
    JobInput = InputBox("Please Enter a vaild job Number", "ATTACHMENT LINK TO JOB NUMBER", "Enter Job Number here")
    If JobInput <> "" Then
        If Nz(DLookup("JobInput", "tblRouting", "[Job Number] = " & JobInput & "")) <> "" Then
            MsgBox ("Serial number already in use")
        End If
    End If
End If
```

If JobInput is Number, omit the single-quotes.

Comment: Hi Gustav, firstly thanks for your help.. I am still having difficulty though.. It's numbers only. The issue is Its throwing up an error 'Can’t find the field ‘l1’ referred to in your expression'   I thought maybe due to being a split DB running the code in only the backend throws an error as well but a different one  'External Name Not Defined' Any idea what maybe causing it? 
I have switched the search to the manufactured table with the same field but has the same error

    If Nz(DLookup("JobInput", "tblManufactured", "JobInput = " & [tblManufactured]![Job Number]!JobInput)) <> "" Then

Comment: Sorry, it should only be _JobInput_, the variable name. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Still breaking on the Nz dlookup line… its saying The Expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error ‘JobInput’…… is it because there’s nothing pointing to the compare field in the table?? Job Number…. 

.
I’ll get you a coffee..

Comment: Thanks! Love coffee. I see now, that the field name was wrong. See edited answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recordset to search for the job number a user inputs into a inputbox.

```
Dim JobInput As String
Dim vSQL As String
Dim rs As Recordset
    
    'Inputing the JobNumber to search for in tblRouting
    JobInput = InputBox("Please Enter a vaild job Number", "ATTACHMENT LINK TO JOB NUMBER", "Enter Job Number here")
    'Creating a count SQL statement for the number entered into the JobInput box
    vSQL = "SELECT count(*) AS FieldCount FROM tblRouting WHERE JobNumber =" & JobInput
    
    'Setting the recordset to variable rs and have it return the query we wrote for the count
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(vSQL)

    'Checking recordset for fieldcount being greater than 0
    With rs
        If !FieldCount > 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Serial already in use.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: Hi xeon921, thanks for your help... Sorry to say I'm still having issues though. Its throwing a error and breaking on the 'set rs = currentDb.OpenRecordset (vSQL)' line.... The error is run-time 3061 too few parameter Expected 1

Comment: Hey sambob_628, i believe i typed your JobNumber field incorrectly. the vSQL line should read like this: vSQL = "SELECT count(*) AS FieldCount FROM tblRouting WHERE [Job Number] =" & JobInput

Comment: Hi Xeon.. Thanks a lot, that fixed it... Is it possible to add multiple criteria to this approach?? IE  looking at the same table (tblrouting) check job input matches Job Number and  then  search if the  operation number is also on the job card,  so within job card 3, operation 4 exists 

Something like ..... vSQL = "SELECT count(*) AS FieldCount FROM tblRouting WHERE [Job Number] =" & JobInput AND WHERE [OPID] = OpInput

Comment: Yes, you can add more criteria! In this case it would be like this: vSQL = "SELECT count(*) AS FieldCount FROM tblRouting WHERE [Job Number] =" & JobInput & " AND [OPID]=" & OpInput.